# Android - Problems with tcpdump when in ad-hoc mode

Tags: android, adhoc, sniffing, tcpdump

Currently I'm working on a project that demands using Android and tcpdump.

A short description of what I do:
I want sniff packets using android. I have built an android application which does this using  by "tcpdump".
Basically the application initiate tcpdump, which dumps the captured packet in a file (in the sdcard). Then I process the captured packets just by opening the file.

The problem :
When the wifi is in managed mode, everything works fine. But, when I put the wifi device in "ad-hoc" the wireless device stops working.

I'm using "Samsung Captivated  S" (SGH - I897), and in order support "overhearing" (promiscuous mode) and ad-hoc I installed the latest "Cyanogen 7" rom ( cm_galaxysmtd_full-126.zip, from: http://download.cyanogenmod.com/?type=nightly&device=galaxysmtd)

I don't know how to solve this and I would really need your help. I suspect 
that "wpa_supplicat" is to blame for that, but most probably I wrong.

Thanks in advance,

Ps: I should also mention that I start an adhoc network using my laptop. Then two android devices join the adhoc network. The android devices (SGH-I897) join the network without a problem. All the devices can ping each other.

Answer (score 1):

only solution for this is described here.
http://www.44actions.com/?p=273